# Pupil tracking program not running after 1 success Build Solution. (C++ and Opencv 3.0)

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I have this program i was trying to run. Its an pupil tracking program. When i try to run the program thru Build Solution, it showed "1 succeeded" but when i tried to run it showed the following errors.

```
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  ConsoleApplication31.cpp
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(87): warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(88): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(89): warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(112): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(114): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(115): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(123): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(127): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(158): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31\consoleapplication31.cpp(173): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is the code. I'm not sure if there is a mistake to code as at first running the build solution and nothing was underlined red to it either. I don't understand where i went wrong. I hope someone can help. Thank you. PS i referred opencv's face and eyes tracking for detecting and tracking eyes.

```
//Get Screen dimensions
void GetDesktopResolution(int& horizontal, int& vertical)
{
RECT desktop;
const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);
horizontal = desktop.right;
vertical = desktop.bottom;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    int horizontal=0;
    int vertical=0;
    int Pupilx;
    int Pupily;
    int scaled_deltax;
    int scaled_deltay;
    int ROIwidth;
    int ROIheight;
    int deltax;
    int deltay;
    int k=0;
    Point Pupil;
    double scaledPupilx;
    double scaledPupily;
    Mat frame;

    //Define a white image to observe changes of coordinates on it
    Mat image = imread( "white.jpg");
if(!image.data)
{
printf( " No image data \n " );
}

GetDesktopResolution(horizontal, vertical);
printf(" The dimensions of the screen are :(%d,%d)\n",horizontal,vertical);

//Check if the face classifier is loaded
if( !faceHaar.load( face_cascade_name ) )
return -1;

//Check if the eyes classifier is loaded
if( !eyesHaar.load( eyes_cascade_name ) )
return -1;

//Take the input from the camera
//capture.readcvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );

capture.open(0);
if( !capture.isOpened( ));
{
    int frame_width = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH );
int frame_height = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT );
printf("The dimensons of the frame :(%d,%d)", frame_width, frame_height);
while( true )
    {
while(k<2)

{
//treat each frame of the capture individually
//frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
capture.read(frame);
if( !frame.empty() )
{
std::vector<Rect> faces;
Mat frame_gray;
Mat ImageROI;
//change the frame to gray-scale
cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
//use histogram equilization
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );
//use the face classifie
faceHaar.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,
Size(30, 30) );

for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
{
    Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
    ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360,
    Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
    std::vector<Rect> eyes;
// for the detected face use the eye classifier
eyesHaar.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30,
30) );

for( int j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
{
    Mat eyeROI = frame_gray(eyes[j]);
    Point center1( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y
    + eyes[j].height*0.5 );
    int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.005 );
    circle(frame, center1, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
    Pupilx = center1.x;
    Pupily = center1.y;
    ROIwidth=eyes[j].width;
    ROIheight=eyes[j].height;
    Point center[2];
    center[k]=center1;
//performing the scaling of the coordintaes to fir to the screen dimensions

if(k==0)
{
scaledPupilx=Pupilx;
scaledPupily=Pupily;
}

else
{
deltax= abs((center[k].x-center[k-1].x));
deltay= abs((center[k].y-center[k-1].y));
scaled_deltax=(deltax*(65535/ROIwidth));
scaled_deltay=(deltay*(65535/ROIheight));
scaledPupilx=center[k-1].x+scaled_deltax;
scaledPupily=center[k-1].y+scaled_deltay;
printf("(%d,%d)", Pupilx, Pupilx);
}

if(k==2)
k=0;
//set the cursor position to the scaled coordinates
SetCursorPos((1366-scaledPupilx),(768-scaledPupily));
printf("(%d,%d)", Pupilx, Pupilx);
}

//define a window for displaying the frame
namedWindow("window_name");
//show the frame with the detected face and eyes on the defined window above
imshow("window_name",frame);
waitKey(10);

}
}
}
}
}
else
{
printf("No captured frame!!");
}

//release window if any key is hit
if( waitKey>=0 )
cvDestroyAllWindows();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Regarding the error, try to indent your code properly and the problem should be easy to see.

Comment: And you really should do something about all those warnings. If the compiler is giving you warnings, it's a certain sign that you are probably doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: Thecodeisunreadableanywaybecauseofthepoorformattingwithnoindentation

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "to indent"?